# HOG descriptor for count people with ceiling view

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, counting, object-detection

I am trying to count people  who goes in or out from a door. I tried `BackgroundSubtractorMOG2` with OpenCV 3.2 on C++ and got some error when detecting people. If two people walk close to each other, I get one object. Then I set a threshold for bigger size object to count as 2 people but the person carrying a suitcase or something else also has a big object size after background subtraction.

So, I found [HOG descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_of_oriented_gradients) followed by [SVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine) to detect people. This method works very good for pedestrian because of their arms and legs.

My questions are that

Is that method also works good for my situation?

Are there any other methods to count people pass a door?

How can I improve my background subtraction method to handle multiple people counting?

Comment: post sample images.

Comment: HOG works well for object detection in general. Yes originally was developed for pedestrian but then many research papers come later to prove that it can be used for other things. So all depend on your training data, if you're using a classifier for pedestrian for video surveillance it might not work very well for your situation.